# Upload image to AWS presigned URL from react native

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, pre-signed-url

im trying to upload an image to AWS Presigned url. I can get presigned url then i can upload an image from Postman, but i try to send from React Native application, just uri info is sent (content://media/external/images/media/108721). I tried a lot of thing but i cant do it. Could you help me please?

I am using ***react-native-image-picker*** to select an image.

```
showImagePicker = () => {
    const options = {
        title: 'Profile Picture',
        storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true,
            path: 'images',
            base64: true,
        },
    };
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        console.log('Response = ', response);

        if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled image picker');
        } else if (response.error) {
            console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        } else if (response.customButton) {
            console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        } else {
            const source = { uri: response.uri };
            const avatarData = response;

            let presignedUrl = "mypresignedurl";
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
            xhr.open('PUT', presignedUrl)
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        console.log('Image successfully uploaded to S3')
                    } else {
                        console.log('Error while sending the image to S3', xhr.responseText)
                    }
                }
            }
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', response.type)
            xhr.setRequestHeader('content-lenght', response.fileSize)
            xhr.send(response.uri);

            this.setState({
                avatarSource: source,
                avatarData: avatarData,
                imageModalVisibilty: true
            });

        }
    });
}
```

I saw many example like this but i just only send uri string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue with another way. I had to get blob data :)

```
export const getBlob = async (fileUri) => {
const resp = await fetch(fileUri);
const imageBody = await resp.blob();
return imageBody;
};

export const uploadImageNew = async (uploadUrl, data) => {
const imageBody = await getBlob(data);

return fetch(uploadUrl, {
    method: "PUT",
    body: imageBody,
});
};
```

[reference](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/179/Upload-a-File-to-an-S3-Pre-Signed-URL-with-React-Native)